Table or view does not exist although the synonyms is created
select * from Schema1.view  --Displays results.
When tried creating synonym "CREATE SYNONYM view_syn for view".
It gives an error of ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid
00980. 00000 -  "synonym translation is no longer valid"
*Cause:    A synonym did not translate to a legal target object. This
could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. The target schema does not exist.
2. The target object does not exist.
3. The synonym specifies an incorrect database link.
4. The synonym is not versioned but specifies a versioned

The CREATE SYNONYM documentation states:

CREATE SYNONYM
Purpose
Use the CREATE SYNONYM statement to create a synonym, which is an alternative name for a table, view, sequence, operator, procedure, stored function, package, materialized view, Java class schema object, user-defined object type, or another synonym. A synonym places a dependency on its target object and becomes invalid if the target object is changed or dropped.
Synonyms provide both data independence and location transparency. Synonyms permit applications to function without modification regardless of which user owns the table or view and regardless of which database holds the table or view. However, synonyms are not a substitute for privileges on database objects. Appropriate privileges must be granted to a user before the user can use the synonym.

Therefore, as the final quoted sentence of the CREATE SYNONYM documentation states "Appropriate privileges must be granted to a user before the user can use the synonym" then, you must also GRANT SELECT ON Schema1.ABC TO schema_name if you want the user schema_name to be able to use the synonym.

The CREATE VIEW documentation also states:

CREATE VIEW
[...]
Prerequisites
[...]
The owner of the schema containing the view must have the privileges necessary to either select (READ or SELECT privilege), insert, update, or delete rows from all the tables or views on which the view is based. The owner must be granted these privileges directly, rather than through a role.

If Schema1.ABC is a VIEW then you need to GRANT the SELECT privilege on the tables upon which the view is based to be able to read the data.

If Schema1.ABC is a view and you do not want to GRANT the SELECT privilege on the underlying tables of a VIEW then you could consider changing Schema1.ABC to a MATERIALIZED VIEW and then you would only need the SELECT privilege on the materialized view and not on the base tables.

Please see above edited question.

In my database, connected as scott, I'm creating a synonym for a table owned by user mike:
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.

SQL> select * from trades;

       COL
----------
       100

Back to scott, create a synonym:
SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.
   
SQL> create synonym abc for mike.trades;

Synonym created.

Can I select from it now? Nope, I got error you got:
SQL> select * from abc;
select * from abc
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Why? Because mike doesn't let me use its table! Grant privileges first!
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.

SQL> grant select on trades to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.

SQL> drop synonym abc;

Synonym dropped.

SQL> create synonym abc for mike.trades;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from abc;

       COL
----------
       100

Now it works.

@Littkefoot: But if I give grants to the tables then what's the need of synonyms, mike can directly do select * from trades right

Mike CAN, because he owns that table. But Scott can't, because table is owned by Mike. Synonym can have a different name (as my example shows). Without it, Scott would have to access Mike's data with select * from mike.trades; with the synonym, it is just select * from trades

We have views already created of those tables and given grant select on views. How can we relate that with the synonyms. I dont want to give grant select to other schema directly
